# Netbeans: thread with logout

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, logout

i have a problem with my program.. When the user is logged out, the program goes in loop and Netbeans suggest many errors:

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java:3125)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3050)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2863)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1070)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:671)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:828)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1335)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at cavonline_client.Connessione.SocketHandler.run(SocketHandler.java:46)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.InternalError
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1590)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1335)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at cavonline_client.Connessione.SocketHandler.run(SocketHandler.java:46)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
and this is another error:
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 49
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2507)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2542)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2614)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2763)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFChar(ObjectInputStream.java:3157)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3054)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2863)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1070)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:671)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:828)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1335)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at cavonline_client.Connessione.SocketHandler.run(SocketHandler.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Instead, in the server's consolle the error is:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2597)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1316)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at cavonline_server.Connessione.Server$SocketHandler.run(Server.java:152)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I don't understand where is the error, and this is the class "SocketHandler":

```
public class SocketHandler implements Runnable {
private static ObjectInputStream in;
public SocketHandler(Socket sock) {
    try {
        SocketHandler.in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} 
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Messaggio message = null;
        System.out.println("Messaggio arrivato");
        while((message = (Messaggio) in.readObject()) != null) {
            ClientConn.receive(message);
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public void interrupt() {
    try {
        SocketHandler.in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

The class "Messaggio" is:

```
public class Messaggio implements Serializable{
   //client invia un messaggio con stringa
   public String sql;
   //dopo dal server riceverà un messaggio con un vector (database)
   public Vector<String> risultati = new Vector();
   public Messaggio(String sql) {
       this.sql = sql;
    }
}
```

Please, help me! I'm going mad...

ClientConn class:

```
public class ClientConn  {

    private static Socket sock;
    private Client client;

    private static Messaggio message;

    protected static Thread thread1;
    protected static Thread thread2;

    private static Vector<String> risultati = new Vector<>();

    public ClientConn() {

        thread1 = Thread.currentThread();
        client = new Client();
        sock = client.connect();

        thread2 = new Thread(new SocketHandler(sock));

        thread2.start();

    } 

    public static void receive(Messaggio message) {

        ClientConn.message = message;

        ClientConn.risultati = message.risultati;

        // gli arriva una notifica di quando può ripartire
        synchronized(thread1) {

            thread1.notify();
        }

    }

    //metodo per settare il messaggio
    public void query(Messaggio message) {

            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

            this.message = message;

            client.send(this.message);

            //aspetta finchè non gli arriva il messaggio
            wait(thread1);

    }

    //metodo che ritorna i risultati del database
    public Vector<String> getResult(){
        return message.risultati;
    }

    public void wait(Thread t) {

        synchronized(t) {

            try {

                t.wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientConn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's happening inside ClientConn.receive(message) ?

Comment: ClientConn.receive(message) is a method inside ClientConn class. i add the code of ClientConn class at the post.